# CKEditor for HTML templates

Tags: html, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I want to use CKEditor to author HTML templates. For instance, E-Mail templates.

So, let's say I want to create a new template which will look like this

> Hello $FirstName,
>
> We have a offer for you!

Obviously, author of this template, may want to format $FirstName as bold (we're editing HTML at least!)

> Hello **$FirstName**,
>
> We have a offer for you!

and after processing this will become

> Hello **Joe**,
>
> We have a offer for you!

if we're sending this to Joe.

But, I want to prevent author formatting some part of my custom variable tag $FirstName, or type within, etc.

> Hello **$First**-Name, << this is BAD!
>
> We have a offer for you!

Can I implement this restriction with CKEditor? If not (is not supported or way too hard) when editor will you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [placeholder plugin](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/plugins/placeholder/placeholder.html). As you can see it can only be edited using dialog. What's more in upcoming [CKEditor 4.3](http://dev.ckeditor.com/query?group=status&milestone=CKEditor+4.3) it was rewritten so the experience will be a lot better.

To build a CKEditor with this plugin, go to its page: http://ckeditor.com/addon/placeholder, add it to your editor and simply build it.